# What kind of reshape is this and why use it?

Tags: python, numpy

Sorry for a very unintelligent question. I've been trying to find an answer for it for some time.

So I was skimming through a guide on "Convolutional Neural Networks" and found it using a `numpy.reshape` function looking like this:

```
testX.reshape([-1, 28, 28, 1])
```

This is chinese to me as I can't imagine it having to do with four dimensions, nor being some sort of a reverse function.

Edit: This is the context of the function. Now I'm not even sure it's a numpy function or not:

```
import tflearn.datasets.mnist as mnist
X, Y, testX, testY = mnist.load_data(one_hot=True)
X = X.reshape([-1, 28, 28, 1])
testX = testX.reshape([-1, 28, 28, 1])
```

Comment: A -1 as a parameter means 'choose the right number to preserve the total array size.'

Comment: Okay, yeah, I can see that. But what is this function supposed to do to whatever 2d array you feed it through?

Comment: Did you actually copy the params correctly? It looks to me like the numpy.reshape expects an int or a tuple.

Comment: The function will reorganize your array of N elements into N/(28*28) 28x28x1 cubes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example (MNIST) the `[-1, 28, 28, 1]` stands for

```
[training_examples, hight, width, channels]
```

-1 for the training examples, as the number is unknown, hight and width should be clear.

Number of channels: Grayscale pics use 1 channel, RBG uses 3 channels.
As MNIST has grayscale pics, here you have 1 (values from 0 to 256).

Comment: That's it! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming you are working with MNIST, or a dataset similar to this with a set of 28 x 28 images.  Perhaps these images are presented in an array of length 784.

```
x = []
for _ in range(10):
    x.append(range(28 ** 2))
np.array(x).reshape([-1, 28, 28, 1])
```

This will convert your dataset into a set of `28 x 28 x 1` matrices, which would be useful if you're trying to learn on an image that is `28 x 28` and only has a single color.

it will also determine that you have `10` images, and convert your array to `10 matrices` with shape `28 x 28 x 1`.

```
np.array(x).reshape([-1, 28, 28, 1]).shape == (10, 28, 28, 1)
```

The reason it's `28 x 28 x 1` instead of `28 x 28` is sometimes this is a cleaner way to interpret that there are `28 x 28` squares and a single color.  It's not necessary to add the single dimensional width if it's confusing you, you could just as easily map it to a matrix with shape `28 x 28`.  But imagine you had a dataset of colored images, you'd probably map it to `28 x 28 x 3` to indicate that it's an image with `28 x 28` squares, and each square has a value for each of the three colors.

Therefore, it's a set of `-1` images, where `-1` means calculate the correct number of images `(10)`, and each image has `28 * 28` values, and give each value it's own dimension `(1)`.